# PulseAudio problems (only showing dummy output)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, skype

I have always avoided using PulseAudio because of how problematic it is, but since Skype 4.3 has now dropped Alsa support, I am forced to use PulseAudio, but one problem; it just doesn't work. I can't remove it because Skype will not work without it (as far as I'm aware) and only show virtual devices in the Audio options. It is only showing dummy output devices and no input devices despite having a built-in microphone. Is there any way to fix this, or better yet is there any way to use Skype without PulseAudio?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Skype 4.2 still supported on Linux?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/675859/is-skype-4-2-still-supported-on-linux)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that PulseAudio hasn't been initialized fully. Try `pulseaudio -k` followed by `pulseaudio --start`. If this still doesn't help, try to restart your system and then check if Skype detects PA correctly.

If it still doesn't work, please provide more info on what you tried (and what failed) in the original question. Also make sure that you are indeed running Skype 4.3.

But if your question is about still using Skype with Alsa only, the answer seems to be: "no".

See also:

- [Is Skype 4.2 still supported on Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675859/is-skype-4-2-still-supported-on-linux)

Comment: Did the job for me. I also run `aplay -l` to list all hardware playback devices to be sure that the sound device is there.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst exploring similar (as yet unresolved) problems i was surprised to note that Pavucontrol panel changes to show devices actually in use, so once you start recording it picks up the device and shows a volume bar. These aren't present until the device is active - strange behaviour, but no doubt useful.