# Is Skype 4.2 still supported on Linux?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, skype, alsa

I am currently using Skype 4.2 but I cannot sign in to the Skype network. (Internet connection is OK and so is the password). And since I'm using Ubuntu without PulseAudio (it doesn't support my soundcard), I [cannot upgrade](http://blogs.skype.com/2014/06/18/skype-4-3-for-linux/) to Skype 4.3:

> This version dropped support for direct Alsa support; please install PulseAudio 4.0 or greater for the best calling experience.

Is Skype 4.2 still supported on Linux? If not, how can I keep using Skype *without* PulseAudio?

Comment: Skype 4.2 is supported on Linux (as you can see, it works), but it is not supported on the Skype network, which is why it won't sign in. You might want to varify that at http://community.skype.com/.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think this question should be closed, though, as other users are likely to end up in the same boat and have this precise question... (I posted an answer linking to an official source.)

Comment: This can' t be the case that your sound card is not supported by pulseaudio. Pulseaudio is not a hardware driver. If alsa supports your card, pulseaudio can be configured to use it through alsa.

Comment: @Pilot6 PulseAudio will run into hissy fits with certain USB DACs (e.g. FiiO X3ii). In my case it incapacitates my computer as soon as I connect the damn device, and I have to perform a hard reboot. While I understand the theoretical arguments that PulseAudio "cannot 'cause it's not hardware driver", it turns out that it actually can. I'm [not](http://wiki.marklesh.com/How-to/Asoundconf) the only one. After I remove PulseAudio, I can use the device with plain Alsa without any issues.

Comment: Your link is an old one. In '10 pulseaudio was not good at all no matter which hardware was used.

Comment: @Pilot6 This is beyond the point. My experience is with 14.04. Trusty will effectively crash with FiiO X3ii when PulseAudio is running. I can provide other links, but this is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Having trouble signing in? Retirement of older versions of Skype](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Having-trouble-signing-in-Retirement-of-older-versions-of-Skype/td-p/3439685) (01-08-2014):

> From today, users with Skype for Linux version 4.2 and older will not be able to sign in to Skype. The error messages user will see during sign in may include “Can’t Connect to Skype” or ”Can’t login on Skype”. To continue using Skype, please update to the latest version.

So it seems that now it is impossible to use Skype without PulseAudio. The attitude from Microsoft seems to be "tough luck".